# How to tell what applications are accessing the hard drive and how frequently?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, monitoring

My hard drive is going crazy and I don't know what application is doing it.

Are there any linux tools for profiling what processes are accessing drives and how frequently?

[top](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm), [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) and the like neatly sort out the memory and cpu hogs, and [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) lets me see the network hogs... but what to use for determining HDD hogs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can install `iotop`

[image]

Comment: Looks great... although no standard repo package for it.  Link is [here](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) for anyone else looking.

Comment: `iotop --accumulated` is great.

Comment: @russ  I had it in my repo, via universe : `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe i386 Packages`

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is using inotify (package is `inotify-tools`) .

Here's an article on [Monitoring file system activity with inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) .

Also see 
[Find which files are read or written to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25442/find-which-files-are-read-or-written-to) .

Answer (score 2):

The new utility **fatrace** can show you exactly! See: https://launchpad.net/fatrace/ or run 'sudo apt-get install fatrace'.  Then run it:

```
# sudo fatrace
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.config/google-chrome/Default/Current Session
chrome(6516): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6514): RW /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_0
chrome(6516): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
chrome(6516): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
wicd(29613): RO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): R /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): CO /etc/ld.so.cache
```

The advantage of **fatrace** is that you get the filename, unlike iotop.  For multi process applications like chrome, you get all the processes in one place.

Comment: also fatrace accepts grep and grep can exclude                                                                             .  eg    fatrace | grep -v "firefox" will exclude firefox

Comment: and multiple exclusions like sudo fatrace | grep -Ev "firefox|tixati|konsole"