# HD Continous read

Tags: hard-drive

Just installed latest update. Now have continous read on hard drive. Sounds like just doing repeated seek for a track on drive.
No problems on update. Update initiated by system after I oked it to start.
Never ending. Does not seem to have much affect on speed loading programs etc.
If I can't stop it will have to do a complete reinstall.
Tks K7AAY, I was not aware of top. It and its mates will be most useful. The problem has gone away for now but I do get it from time to time. Different this time as it did not affect the operation this time.
de Barry VK2AAB

Comment: 1) Have you checked the drive before install for the S.M.A.R.T data? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en  2) Install one or more of the tools mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/q/29566/197910 and look for the app which is re-re-re-re-writing. Once you've done both, please click [edit] and add the results to your question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, click [edit]

Comment: Look in /var/log/apt/history.log for what "latest update" consisted of. Copy the list into your question above.

Comment: It stopped the repeated reading a few hours after I lodged my question. pas ax did not show anything remarkable. kworker did seem to be ocuring but that might be a normal call of that routine.

Comment: Tks K7AAY de VK2AAB   it stopped after a few hours. ps ax showed kworker active but that may be normal.