# Can I get the commands from history executed in bash in the last 15 mins?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I want to put in place a cron job that sends me notification about a particular command executed in the last 15 mins. I can get the history along with timestamp using `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T'`, but I couldn't really figure out how to filter it according to commands executed in the last 15 min only. Can someone suggest me a way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easier if you use a different time format (which you can, since setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to any value is enough for bash to keep track of time). So, use the Unix timestamp, and the difference between now and then:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%s ' history |  awk -v now=$(date +%s) '(now - $2) < 15*60'
```

`date +%s` is the current Unix timestamp, and the second column of history's output is the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` field, so this checks if the difference in seconds is less than 15 minutes.

However, if your intention is to monitor command usage, then this really isn't the way to go about it. Setup [auditd](https://askubuntu.com/a/51432/158442) instead (it can be configured to watch for command execution).

Comment: Thanks, that works as intended. I wanted to have a quick fix before i think of heavyweight solution.

Comment: With GNU awk, you *could* do `gawk 'systime() - mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$2" "$3)) < 15*60'` if you *really* liked `%F %T`